# changing default emacs theme to downloaded theme

Tags: themes

I have just downloaded a matrix theme name **matrix-theme-source-code.el**
and I want to install it on my emacs, I have read that I should do the following thing in my **.emacs** :-

```
(add-to-list 'custom-theme-load-path "~/.emacs.d/themes/")

(load-file "~/.emacs.d/themes/matrix-theme-source-code.el")
```

After doing this, I tried to do `M-x` and `customize-themes Ret`
It should display me my theme
but there's is no theme, except the default themes provided by the emacs.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have to load my preferred theme (named "foo" in this example):

```
(setq custom-safe-themes t)
(load-theme 'foo 'noconfirm)
```

First check your logs with `C-h e`, it might say why your theme isn't being applied.

`custom-safe-themes` can be `t` or a list of themes.  Since themes can contain arbitrary code, it's better to whitelist the ones you use, but for testing set it to `t`.

Check that you definitely installed the theme correctly.  `load-theme` says the file should be named `foo-theme.el`.  `load-theme` calls `enable-theme` at the end, so if you use `load-file` instead you might need to do `(enable-theme 'foo)`.

You might also like the theme `calmer-forest` in melpa.